# Missing Extract Type on Data Extract Activity

Tags: data

I would like to create a data extract activity.
However, the extract type is blank, so i cannot continuous to create the job, any recommend?

[image]

Answer (score 1):

Your account doesn't have any extracts provisioned. Contact the Marketing Cloud and find out what extracts you should have. The tracking extract and the Data Extension Extract are probably most common.